# Refresh page still display animation?

Tags: jquery, css

When I refresh the page, it always shows me the `<div>` for 0.2 sec on Chrome, but not on Safari.  It does this even if I put a `display none`.

```css
#menuheaderdrop.active i:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: inT 0.8s forwards;
  animation: inT 0.8s forwards;
}

#menuheaderdrop {
  display: none !important;
}

@-webkit-keyframes inT {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(9px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(9px) rotate(135deg);
  }
}

@keyframes inT {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(9px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(9px) rotate(135deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="menuheaderdrop">
            <i></i><i></i><i></i>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If anyone could help, that would be great!

Comment: the time to load the CSS i suppose .. so make sure the CSS is loaded fast or use inline style

Comment: Your formatting! it drive me crazy .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by your style sheet loading after your html elements.

One way to resolve this is by adding the inline css directly to your html element, then change the style rule when the document is ready.

```
<div id="menuheaderdrop" style="display: none;">
   ...
</div>
```

You can then use jQuery to alter the style attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menuheaderdrop').css('display', 'block');
}
```

Your css keyframe animation may run too soon, so consider creating a class for this animation, then add the class to the element when the page is fully loaded.

```
.menuAnimation {
    display: block;
    animation:inT 0.8s forwards;
}
```

Then add the class using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menuheaderdrop').addClass('menuAnimation');
}
```